# Object injected by Dagger into fragment is null

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I have no idea why my object Coffee is null after inject. In java code, this same code worked.

class app:

```
    @Singleton
    @Component(modules = [AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, ContributesBuilder::class,
    FirstModule::class])
    interface ApplicationComponent {

        @Component.Builder
        interface Builder{


     @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: Application): Builder
        fun build(): ApplicationComponent
    }

    fun inject(app: LocationPickerApplication)
}
```

contributes class:

```
@Module
abstract class ContributesBuilder{

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun bindFirstFragment(): FirstFragment

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun bindSecondFragment(): SecondFragment

}
```

my module with return coffee

```
@Module
class FirstModule {

    @Provides
    fun getCoffee(): Coffee{
        return Coffee()
    }

}
```

and class Coffee:

```
class Coffee (name: String = "name")
```

What can be wrong here ?

and here is my Fragment, coffee here is null:

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var coffee: Coffee

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "a $coffee", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance() =
            FirstFragment()
    }
}
```

too many time wasted, and I still don't know what is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Missing

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)//this missing
    }
```

Comment: with this, I have still null :(